# A crypto-mining process keeps appearing on server

Tags: server, security, malware

I recently started using a remote Ubuntu server for development and testing machine. However the hosting provider reported a crypto mining process was running and he had to shut down the server.

There were no logs or any data that could identify that process or anything that could help figure out what happened. Then it happened again, but this time they captured this:

```
PID    USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
246369 redis     20   0   13928  11444    908 S 746.7   0.2  62801:13 /tmp/kmv --pool pool.hashvault.pro:80 --username TRTLv2TW8sjC5LmSpiDdRZ2ndnEwPRpJ9Lgz3vgGY2CTSLkLeKAUFMefEeT6idQBxzSLsXfAvAqfhH5zkxMM3sHu2RL8xh1n5Pg --password x --algorithm chukwa_v2
```

The only ports that are open are Redis port, 6379.

```
admin@nicotine2:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                 Action      From
--                 ------      ----
22                 ALLOW       Anywhere
9200               DENY        Anywhere
6379/tcp           ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9200 (v6)          DENY        Anywhere (v6)
6379/tcp (v6)      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I checked, there was no `/tmp/kmv` folder anywhere to be found. This has happened for the 2nd time.

Any clues, recommendations or suggestions to avoid this?

Answer (score 24):

Redis has a well know remote code execution vulnerability if you do not enable authentication.

This article has more information on your exact issue.

https://www.trendmicro.com/en_gb/research/20/d/exposed-redis-instances-abused-for-remote-code-execution-cryptocurrency-mining.html

Comment: From the screenshot, you are of course correct - it's Redis that has been exploited and is consuming all CPU.

Comment: Running _any_ non-public service on the Internet without authentication is a bad idea.

Comment: @gronostaj tell that to all the unsecured HTTPS servers. They just let anyone fetch pages without a login! Even Ask Ubuntu is vulnerable.

Comment: @user253751 Hence "non-public" in my comment.

Answer (score 7):

The really good question is: What did you install?

There is a good chance you installed an application infected with or vulnerable to this cryptomining software. This can also be in [Docker images](https://threatpost.com/malicious-docker-cryptomining-images/165120/).

So uninstall everything (or reinstall a blank image might be even better), and monitor your server while installing stuff. You should see a huge CPU spike when you install the infected cryptomining software.

EDIT: If you installed an older and vulnerable version of ElasticSearch (or an unofficial Docker image), the answer is pretty obvious: Install the latest, official and security patched version.

EDIT 2: TheHermit has the correct answer here, as it is the redis process that hosts the cryptomining exploit.

Comment: elastic search and redis. 
redis was installed from the ubuntu repository with apt-get command

Comment: And what about Elastic? There was an [earlier vulnerability](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/z0miner-botnet-hunts-for-unpatched-elasticsearch-jenkins-servers/) where Elastic was targeted by a crypto mining bot, and [pool.hashvault.pro](https://hashvault.pro/) is a Monero mining pool, so maybe there is a connection?

Comment: I don't know as you can see port 9200 is already blocked earlier. But the question is how to avoid this in future

Answer (score 0):

Well for one allowing SSH on Port 22 from anywhere is a Security Risk, recommend limiting it down to a IP that is used for Management and changing default Port 22 to something in a higher range. We need to see more processes of the Server, Redis should be configured with Auth.